# Find with exec causing repeated output?

Tags: find

What is causing the output of ls to be printed twice?

```
$find . -exec ls -l {} \;
total 340
-rw-rw-r-- 1 w w 163244 Aug 26 19:25 apt-list--installed.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 w w 162078 Aug 26 19:25 apt-list.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 w w     29 Aug 27 08:29 df1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 w w     31 Aug 27 08:22 df2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 w w      9 Aug 26 23:24 f1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 w w      5 Aug 26 23:21 f2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 w w     27 Aug 27 11:40 o.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 w w 9 Aug 26 23:24 ./f1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 w w 163244 Aug 26 19:25 ./apt-list--installed.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 w w 27 Aug 27 11:40 ./o.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 w w 5 Aug 26 23:21 ./f2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 w w 162078 Aug 26 19:25 ./apt-list.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 w w 29 Aug 27 08:29 ./df1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 w w 31 Aug 27 08:22 ./df2
```

As you can see the files are listed twice in the above output. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because `find` runs `ls` on all the files and directories it finds, and when `ls` is run on a directory, it lists its contents by default. Thus each file is listed when `find` processes it *and* when it processes its containing directory.

To avoid this, you can tell `ls` to handle everything as a file (`ls -ld`), or use `find`’s `ls`-like output if it has one (`find . -ls`). Both of these will also result in directories being listed individually in the same way as files; you can avoid that by filtering on file types (*e.g.* `-type f`).

Comment: thanks. that helps greatly.  Another way to fix `find . -type f -exec ls -l {} \;`

Comment: Yes, if you only want to see regular files.

Comment: what are the other types of files that `-type f` will not search for.

Comment: Block/character devices, links, named pipes and sockets.

Comment: gr8, like `-type d` for directories and `-type f` for regular files. Is there any search equivalent for device files, links, named pipes and sockets etc.

Comment: `-type b`, `-type c`, `-type l` etc.; see `man find` for details.